# Ошибка сокета dkim Milter service local:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, postfix, dkim

Настраиваю почтовый сервис на сервере debian
Но почему-то dkim не подписывает письма, в днс запись валидная, а вот логи жалуются на сокет

Конфиг postfix

```
root@api-hype:# cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep smtpd_milters
smtpd_milters = local:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = local:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Конфиг dkim

```
root@api-hype:# cat /etc/opendkim.conf | grep Socket
Socket local:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Сам сокет

```
root@api-hype:# ls -lha /var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
srwxrwxr-x 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Apr 14 14:12 /var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Логи

```
Apr 14 14:18:23 api-hype postfix/smtpd[225040]: warning: connect to Milter service local:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Если postfix работает в chroot, то значит нужно указывать `local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`

Comment: @andreymal с этим значением та же ошибка

Comment: А, замените `local:` на `unix:` наверное

Comment: @andreymal
Apr 14 15:45:07 api-hype postfix/smtpd[227087]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

Comment: Поехали по второму кругу — если postfix работает в chroot, то значит нужно указывать `unix:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`

Comment: @andreymal Apr 14 15:57:53 api-hype postfix/smtpd[227816]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

Comment: Я не знаю что происходит, но на моём сервере прописано `unix:run/opendkim/opendkim.sock` без слэша в начале и у меня всё работает — может действительно слэш лишний?

Comment: А сокет лежит по этому пути?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло значение

```
Socket                  inet:12345@localhost
```